# Study the convergence $f(n)= \frac{2}{7}, \frac{5}{12} \cdots \frac{3n-1}{5n+2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

We have the chain  $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(n)= \frac{2}{7}, \frac{5}{12} \cdots \frac{3n-1}{5n+2}$ and $f(1) =0$, so I have to find the limit and study the convergence.

If the function is convergent, that means it has a limit. That limit in my opinion is 3/5?

Comment: The second one :)

Comment: There is a sequence $f(n)=(3n-1)/(5n+2)$ and $f(1)=2/7\neq 0$ the limit is $3/5$

Comment: Shouldnt just we take the highest power in the denominator and numerator? and it is 3/5?

Comment: Just dividing top and bottom by $n$ is sufficient to see that the limit exists and has value $3/5$.

Answer (score 1):

how rigorous is the answer supposed to? The simple proof is that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n -1}{5n +2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3-\frac{1}{n}}{5+\frac{2}{n}}=\frac{3}{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Though a simple question, students get confused because they are institutionalized.It happens and check-point for student.

Looking at the last term of the series,numerator: 3 times a " extreme larger quantity" 
Denominator : 5 times a "extreme large quantity". The " extreme larger quantity" cancels out leaving 3/5.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
if
$f(n)
=\dfrac{an+b}{cn+d}
$
with
$c\ne 0$
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)-\dfrac{a}{c}
&=\dfrac{an+b}{cn+d}-\dfrac{a}{c}\\
&=\dfrac{(an+b)c-a(cn+d)}{c(cn+d)}\\
&=\dfrac{can+cb-acn-ad}{c(cn+d)}\\
&=\dfrac{cb-ad}{c(cn+d)}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$